# TensorFlow tfrecord edit (read and then write to file) OutOfRange error

Tags: tensorflow, tfrecord

In [src/datasets/h36m_edit.py](https://github.com/MatthewD1993/hmr_extend/blob/5a496695c0ebdc8207a847f4d83c49426a25e934/src/datasets/h36m_edit.py#L196-L229):

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
    coder = ImageCoder()

    fqueue = tf.train.string_input_producer(files, num_epochs=1, shuffle=False, name="input")
    _, example_serialized = reader.read(fqueue)

    sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

    fidx = 0
    total_imgs = 0
    image, image_size, label, center, fname, pose, shape, gt3d, has_smpl3d = parse_example_proto(example_serialized)

    while not coord.should_stop():
        fidx += 1
        tf_filename = out_path% fidx

        print('Starting tfrecord file %s \n' % tf_filename)
        with tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(tf_filename) as writer:
            for i in tqdm(range(train_shards)):  # min(train_shards, image_bs.shape[0])
                image_v, image_size_v, label_v, center_v, fname_v, pose_v, shape_v, gt3d_v, has_smpl3d_v = sess.run(
                    [image, image_size, label, center, fname, pose, shape, gt3d, has_smpl3d])
                image_s = coder.encode_jpeg(image_v)
                example = convert_to_example_wmosh(image_s, fname_v, image_size_v[0], image_size_v[1],
                                                   label_v, center_v, gt3d_v, pose_v, shape_v)
                writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
                total_imgs += 1

    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
```

Sometimes the inner loop stops before it reaches the maximum iter limit (train_shards) 500.

```
100%|██████████| 500/500 [00:02<00:00, 225.07it/s]
Starting tfrecord file /home/cdeng/tf_datasets/tf_records_human36m_wjoints/train_modified/train_0011.tfrecord 

 96%|█████████▌| 478/500 [00:02<00:00, 225.58it/s]Starting tfrecord file /home/cdeng/tf_datasets/tf_records_human36m_wjoints/train_modified/train_0012.tfrecord 

100%|██████████| 500/500 [00:02<00:00, 230.37it/s]
```

And when it writes to the number 625 tfrecord file, there is OutOfRange error (it supposes to finish with more than 3000  tfrecord files, cause human36m train has 1559985 images and each tfrecord contains 500 images). I guess it's because the *image queue* is not handled correctly, maybe the producer is too slow?

```
/home/cdeng/tf_datasets/tf_records_human36m_wjoints/train_modified/train_0625.tfrecord 
 36%|███▌      | 180/500 [00:00<00:01, 221.50it/s]2019-01-13 22:47:40.946736: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Out of range: FIFOQueue '_0_input' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 1, current size 0)
     [[Node: ReaderReadV2 = ReaderReadV2[_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](TFRecordReaderV2, input)]]
2019-01-13 22:47:40.946816: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Out of range: FIFOQueue '_0_input' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 1, current size 0)
     [[Node: ReaderReadV2 = ReaderReadV2[_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](TFRecordReaderV2, input)]]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cdeng/star_repos/hmr/src/datasets/h36m_edit.py", line 233, in <module>
    [image, image_size, label, center, fname, pose, shape, gt3d, has_smpl3d])
  File "/home/cdeng/.virtualenvs/hmr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 895, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/cdeng/.virtualenvs/hmr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1124, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/cdeng/.virtualenvs/hmr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1321, in _do_run
    options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/cdeng/.virtualenvs/hmr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1340, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OutOfRangeError: FIFOQueue '_0_input' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 1, current size 0)
     [[Node: ReaderReadV2 = ReaderReadV2[_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](TFRecordReaderV2, input)]]
     [[Node: ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/ParseExample/_21 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_52_ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/ParseExample", tensor_type=DT_INT64, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]()]]

Caused by op u'ReaderReadV2', defined at:
  File "/home/cdeng/star_repos/hmr/src/datasets/h36m_edit.py", line 204, in <module>
    _, example_serialized = reader.read(fqueue)
  File "/home/cdeng/.virtualenvs/hmr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/io_ops.py", line 194, in read
    return gen_io_ops._reader_read_v2(self._reader_ref, queue_ref, name=name)
  File "/home/cdeng/.virtualenvs/hmr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_io_ops.py", line 423, in _reader_read_v2
    queue_handle=queue_handle, name=name)
  File "/home/cdeng/.virtualenvs/hmr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 767, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/cdeng/.virtualenvs/hmr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2630, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/cdeng/.virtualenvs/hmr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1204, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

OutOfRangeError (see above for traceback): FIFOQueue '_0_input' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 1, current size 0)
     [[Node: ReaderReadV2 = ReaderReadV2[_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](TFRecordReaderV2, input)]]
     [[Node: ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/ParseExample/_21 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_52_ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/ParseExample", tensor_type=DT_INT64, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]()]]


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: My calculation is wrong, human36m train only has 312188 images, around 625 tfrecord files. So the code should stop after that much processing.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
Two comments:

1. tqdm could be wrong when the loop is running too fast.
2. when the queue is empty at the end, OutOfRange error will be thrown out, a good practice is to add exception handling as suggested in [QueueRunner](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/threading_and_queues#queuerunner)